# I need to sum the word that are from the same files in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to find the same words from different files in Python this codes works, but I need to sum the same words from the result that I get from the same files. How can I implement, please help me, I appreciate :)

```
from os import listdir

with open("C:/Users/Desktop/Archives/test/result.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in listdir("C:/Users/Desktop/Archives/test/sources/books/"):
        with open('C:/Users/Desktop/Archives/test/xfiles/texts/' + filename) as currentFile:
            text = currentFile.read()
            if ('work' in text):
               
                f.write('The word excist in the file ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
            else:
                f.write('Does not excist' + filename[:-4] + '\n')**
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Notice that `'work' in 'blah blahblahbworking blah'` will return `True`

Comment: @OlvinRoght how to count the sum of the word 'work' that appears in three different files??